# New Line on paragraph emelement <br> not working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, paragraph

Hi i'm currently working on this asp.net webform
stock with this problem in my paragraph tag 
in my html part

```
<p>D1D2 submitted successfully.
" Holded lots: 
  Failed to hold:                                                            
    lot try
  mik
  navi
"
</p>
```

In browser it renders in straight line as a paragraph supposed to be.
Can i force it to be look like in sample bellow ?

```
 D1D2 submitted successfully. 
  Holded lots:   
  Failed to hold:                                                            
     lot try
  mik
  navi
```

I know break tag will solve it but it's a string so the break tag  will only show 
 it as text.
Note:
The text inside the paragraph is a server response.

I hope you understand what i mean.
Thank you

Comment: To split text into separate lines, you need `<br>`. Or you need to split it into separate paragraphs: separate `<p>` elements.

Comment: <br> wont work because the text inside is wrap in " " so it will only display as text. Also i cant separate it o other <p> because the text inside is from the server response

Comment: @Berzerk25 use CSS elements. Edit your `p` element to  `<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">`and it should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply right your code like.

```
<pre><p>D1D2 submitted successfully.
" Holded lots: 
  Failed to hold:                                                     
    lot try
  mik
  navi
"
</p></pre>
```